# Are local variables in a compound switch statement initialized when the `default:` label is put outside the braces?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Normally when using a `switch` statement, you cannot define *and* initialize variables local to the compound statement, like

```
switch (a)
{
  int b = 5;  /* Initialization is skipped, no matter what a is */

  case 1:
    /* Do something */
    break;
  default:
   /* Do something */
   break;
}
```

However, since the `switch` statement is a statement like `for` or `while`, there is no rule against not using a compound statement, [look here for examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8118009/1029106). But this would mean, that a label may be used between the closing parenthesis after the `switch` keyword and the opening brace.

So in my opinion, it would be possible and allowed to use a `switch` statement like this:

```
switch (a)
  default:
{
  int b = 5;  /* Is the initialization skipped when a != 1? */
    /* Do something for the default case using 'b' */
    break;

  case 1: // if a == 1, then the initialization of b is skipped.
    /* Do something */
    break;
}
```

My question: Is the initialization necessarily performed in this case (a != 1)? From what I know of the standards, yes, it should be, but I cannot find it directly in any of the documents I have available. Can anyone provide a conclusive answer?

And before I get comments to that effect, yes, I know this is not a way to program in the real world. But, as always, I'm interested in the boundaries of the language specification. I'd never tolerate such a style in *my* programming team!

Comment: @Mat No, that's just the idea: Labels in a `switch` statement may appear after the closing parenthesis until the end of the statement (usually compound), so the `default:` label outside the braces would be legal IMHO. Confusing, yes, definitely! But no missing braces.

Comment: So are you asking whether `b` is valid if the `case 1` is taken?  This is really no different to `goto foo; { int b = 5; foo: ... }`.

Comment: Ok, well that's certainly confusing...

Comment: Pretty good, confusing question..

Comment: @OliCharlesworth No, that's not my question. My question: Is it required by the Standard (C89 or later) that b shall be properly initialized when `a != 1` (i.e. the `default:` case is taken)? I'd assume, yes, but I can find no specific clause, and I'm wondering if the general clause (initialize when entering a compound statement) is applicable in this situation.

Comment: Nobody mentioned Duff's device yet? Look it up for some more of the horrors of `switch`.

Comment: @ugoren Well, I wouldn't call that 'horrors', even though it is confusing initially. The [sample](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8118009/1029106) I found in H&S is 'horror' (using your words). Better explained: If deemed necessary, and properly commented, I could accept the use of Duff's device; I _never_ would accept the H&S sample.

Comment: So, we're all agreed that if a==1, then b is not initialized. And the question is, if a != 1, is b initialized? It might be worth editing the question accordingly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most people think of a `switch` as a mutiple if, but it is technically a calculated `goto`. And the `case <cte>:` and `default:` are actually labels. So the rules of `goto` apply in these cases.

Your both your examples are syntactically legal, but in the second one, when `a==1` the `b` initialization will be skipped and its value will be undefined. No problem as long as you don't use it.

**REFERENCE**:

According to C99 standard, 6.2.4.5, regarding automatic variables:

> If an initialization is speciﬁed for the object, it is performed each time the declaration is reached in the execution of the block;

So the variable is initialized each time the execution flow reaches the initialization, just as it were an assignment. And if you jump over the initialization the first time, then the variable is left uninitialized.

Comment: But is `b` guaranteed to be initialized when `a != 1`?

Comment: _No_ in your first example; _yes_ in your second. Please, see the reference to the standard in the updated answer.